# Which hardware can install debian stretch arm64?

Tags: debian, qt5, arm64, debian-stretch

I have a mutant debian9.6 arm64 OS.
Its package source is not available for solving install dependencies.
My hardware can install this mutant but the original debian9.6 arm64 is not bootable.
So I want to find an available hardware to install the original arm64 debian9.6 and build Qt5 libraries.
That's all my question.

Comment: No. I am master of rpi4. The hardware what I mentioned above is not related to this topic. I just want to find a computer to install debian9.6 arm64. The hardware what I am currently using is 48core arm processor and 128G ram and disk raid, a real monster.

Comment: why is this tagged `qt5`?

Comment: @umläute I build qt5.14.2 for this specific OS.

Comment: nice, but I think this is unrelated to the question.